# Se modifica la palabra 'Descripción' automaticamente al cerrar el archivo

Tags: vscode

Necesito ayuda de las siguientes imágenes.
No sé por qué, pero cuando cierro el archivo y vuelvo a abrir la palabra 'Descripción' está cambiando a 'Descripci?n'. a la palabra incorrecta

Estoy usando Spell Checker & Spanish - Code Spell Checker.

Te agradeceré con tu ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Suena mas a un problema de editor de texto...has probado a abrir con otro editor y guardar a ver si te hace el mismo cambio,?

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, así como dices fue el problema de editor de texto. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Eso solía pasar por la meta etiqueta charset del documento HTML.

Verifica que tu documento HTML tenga lo siguiente:

meta charset="utf-8"

Comment: Amigo gracias, fui muy tonto de no haberme fijado el VScode. Él 
codificación de HTML no estaba configurado en utf-8. Gracias

Comment: Nada amigo, es un gusto poder ayudar.